# Scales with Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I change the scale in the transform of an object depending on the rotation?

```
if (hand.transform.rotation.z ==30f)
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 180, 33));
}

if (hand.transform.rotation.z == -30f)
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 180, 33)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scale of a gameobject by using the attribute :

`transform.localScale = new Vector3(x, y, z);`